# Comparing bytes[] and String.getBytes()

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I'm debugging my custom implementation of OAuth (`shindig` and `spring-security-oauth` libraries).

Regardless of shindig and spring-security details, I create a hash using `sha()` and then pass it to spring-security-oauth. I expect the hashes to be equal, but they're not.

**shindig**

`bytes[] shindigHash = sha(someBytes);` // [docs for sha()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha%28byte%5B%5D%29)

**spring-security-oauth**

```
bytes[] b = str.getBytes("UTF-8");` // String str passed in from
```

I also tried `bytes[] b = str.getBytes();` for the default encoding, but it didn't equal `shindigHash` when I compared each of `b`'s and `shindigHash`'s elements.

**EDIT**

```
for j = 0 .. b.length // same as shindigHash length
   print shindigHash[j] ... b[j]
end
visually compare results
```

Comment: Where is str comming from? How are you comparing the byte arrays? Also, sha() is deprecated.

Comment: @Antimony, updated above per your `comparison` question. I'd prefer to keep the same library, i.e. not update deprecated sha(), as multiple projects use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBytes()` does not return a hash. It returns the byte representation of a string. So they will never correspond.

One possible representation of a SHA-1 (or some other hash) is a string of hex digits.

"af45deadbeef"

That's a string. Calling `getBytes()` on it does not return the value of the hash. Why?

Well, consider a trivial hash:

000000000000000

That's a bunch of zero bytes. the `byte[]` would be `{ 0, 0, 0, ... }`.

However,

```
"00000000000000".getBytes("utf-8")
```

will return

```
 { 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30 .... } /* those are hex 30's */
```

The UTF-8 representation of '0' is 0x30, not 0x00.

So, if the string contains the hex representation of a hash, then you will need to either convert the `byte[]` to a String containing it's hex representation, or convert the string to a `byte[]` by converting each pair of characters to a `byte`.

Comment: What if `str` is a signature? My understanding was that the `str.getBytes("UTF-8")` would return the signature `str` as a byte[]?

Comment: Nope. Let me try to clarify my answer, that's exactly what I was trying to explain.